# Rails Turbo.visit with post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I am trying to initiate a post request programatically.

```
Turbo.visit('documents/path', { data: { 'turbo-method': 'post' } });
```

This is not working, it triggers a GET request.

Comment: Could you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

On [docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#form-submissions) is one way for doing a post by JS/Turbo, but based on a Form Element:

«To submit a  element programmatically, invoke the `HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()` method and pass an `<input type="submit"> or <button>` element as an optional parameter.»

To do it purely programmatically, the only way I know would be to send a regular post request, without any turbo, to the server, and respond via turbo channel, not turbo stream! [My gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/render_turbo_stream) does this. Depends on the use case.

In my opinion, the cleaner and preferable way in most cases would be turbo-stream, so this issue could be a feature request. But you also have to send the CSRF token by post.